# Can Plotly for Python plot a polygon with one or multiple holes in it?

Tags: plotly, polygon, plotly-python

A simple example would be

```
shape_a = Point(0,0).buffer(10)
shape_b = Point(0,0).buffer(5)
shape_c = shape_a-shape_b
```

[image: Ring Shape]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:
Well. *fill='toself'* also works, if the boundary coords of the holes are appended (separated by None) to the exterior coords in an opposite clock direction.

I found a workaround myself, by using *fill='tonext'*.
Prerequisite is you need to draw the interior boundary right before the exterior one.
In the scenario of multiple holes, you will have to connect them first in one scatter object, via 'None' in the coords lists.

```
shape_a = Point(0,0).buffer(10)
shape_b = Point(0,0).buffer(2)
shape_d = Point(5,0).buffer(1)

shape_c = shape_a - shape_b
shape_c = shape_c - shape_d

fig = go.Figure(layout=go.Layout(width=640, height=640))
x_a, y_a = shape_a.exterior.xy
x_b, y_b = shape_b.exterior.xy
x_d, y_d = shape_d.exterior.xy
int_x = list(x_b) +  [None] + list(x_d)
int_y = list(y_b) +  [None] + list(y_d)


fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=list(int_x), y=list(int_y), fill='none', showlegend=False))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=list(x_a), y=list(y_a), name='polygon_with_holes', fill='tonext'))
```

Answer (score 0):

- normally I associate geometry (**shapely** objects) with mapping geometry
- it's simple to layer *geojson* onto a **mapbox** trace
- demonstrated below with additional object with multiple holes

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

shape_a = Point(3, 3).buffer(10)
shape_b = Point(3, 3).buffer(5)
shape_c = shape_a - shape_b

shape_2 = Point(15,15).buffer(10)
for p in [Point(a,b).buffer(2) for a,b in zip(np.linspace(8, 22, 8), np.linspace(8,22, 4))]:
    shape_2 = shape_2 - p



px.scatter_mapbox(lat=[0], lon=[0], mapbox_style="carto-positron").update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "zoom": 2,
        "layers": [
            {"source": shape_c.__geo_interface__, "type": "fill", "color": "green"},
            {"source": shape_2.__geo_interface__, "type": "fill", "color": "yellow"},

        ],
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: This is nice that it has an interface for Shapely! Is there a way to get rid of the map background?

Comment: just change background layer `mapbox_style="white-bg"`