# How do I repair a polygon displayed in with plotly plot_geo() so that its colour doesn't fill the whole map?

Tags: python, r, plotly, maps, polygon

I'm using plotly in R to plot the world map polygon data from the tmap package. It all works fine, except that it seems that the fill from the polygon for South Africa is filling the whole map as well. I assume this is caused by the fact that the South Africa polygon has a hole in the middle (where Lesotho is).

Is there some way that I can repair the South Africa polygon?
Or perhaps as different way of displaying the data so that this issue doesn't occur?

```
library(plotly)
library(tmap)

data(World)
plot_geo(World, color = ~continent, showlegend=FALSE)
```

[image: map of the world with fill issues]

I determined South Africa to be the cause, as this is what it looks like when I remove it from my data:

[image: map of the world without South Africa]

I tried using fill="tonext" as it seemed like [this thread on polygons with holes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70965145/can-plotly-for-python-plot-a-polygon-with-one-or-multiple-holes-in-it/70966112#70966112) might be answering a similar issue, but fill="tonext" simply removed the fill from the map (and fill="toself" didn't make any difference).

[image: world map with no fill]

Using:
R 4.2.2
plotly 4.10.1
tmap 3.3-3

Comment: What is the `World` data from? I tried looking this up in the plotly and tmap packages but couldn't find it.

Comment: It's part of the tmap package, as detailed [on their shapes page here](https://r-tmap.github.io/tmap/reference/Shapes.html).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Not sure what happened on my end but it seems to work now.